# Как отключить подстветку синтаксиса кода в Netbeans 7?

Tags: ide, netbeans

Собственно вопрос, как отключить подстветку синтаксиса кода в Netbeans 7 для java?

Comment: это такой способ "учиться как в блокноте", но с доступом к отладчику? :)

Comment: да

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это очень дурная идея. Никогда раньше не слышал, чтобы кому-то такое в голову приходило. Я понятия не имею зачем вам это безумие понадобилось, но теоретически это возможно. NetBeans имеет специальный реестр (XML-файл) где осуществляется привязка MIME-типов и обработчков подсветки и т.п... если его найти и изъять оттуда соответствующие записи, то NetBeans будет думать, что это просто текстовый файл.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Сбить там всё на один стиль.

Думаю, это работа на 1-2 минуты.